# How can I change the colour of only bottom border of text-box with multicolor in html/css?

Tags: html, css

I am having a text box and I can set the border colour. I want to change only the bottom colour of the text box. Not only that, the bottom should be multi coloured. Like the image:[image: TextBox]

How can I achieve this? Please help

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use CSS Gradients along with CSS Positioning to simulate such effect. For example :-

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

textarea {
  resize: none;
  height: 100px;
  width: 400px;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
}

div {
  margin: 40px;
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  border-radius: 4px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

div:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 5px;
  background: linear-gradient(to right, #ee585b 0%,#ee585b 33%,#ee585b 33%,#f8d270 33%,#f8d270 66%,#f8d270 66%,#20b5ca 66%,#20b5ca 100%);
  bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<div><textarea></textarea></div>
```

Here, am doing nothing but using an `:after` pseudo element and setting a gradient to that. Rest, am using positioning to set it to the bottom and than I use `overflow: hidden;` on the wrapper to make sure that it gets that `border-radius` effect and is **not** *pointy on the edges*.

There are other ways to do this, by setting `:before` or `:after` pseudo along with another stray element and setting `background` for all the three but that's not optimal at all imo.

---

> Note: Make sure you use `class` or an `id` in your HTML for this
>   particular `textarea` and change my CSS selectors accordingly. Am
>   using basic tag level selectors just for the demonstration purpose.

Answer (score 0):

```css
div:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 5px;
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(to right, #ee585b 0%,    #ee585b 33%, #f8d270 33%, #f8d270 66%, #20b5ca 66%, #20b5ca 100%);
  background-image: -o-linear-gradient(to right, #ee585b 0%,    #ee585b 33%, #f8d270 33%, #f8d270 66%, #20b5ca 66%, #20b5ca 100%);
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(to right, #ee585b 0%,    #ee585b 33%, #f8d270 33%, #f8d270 66%, #20b5ca 66%, #20b5ca 100%);
  background-image: linear-gradient(to right, #ee585b 0%,    #ee585b 33%, #f8d270 33%, #f8d270 66%, #20b5ca 66%, #20b5ca 100%);
  bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is alternate solution for it.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.sg-container
{
width:500px;
height:300px;
margin:200px auto;
border:1px solid #dcdcdc;
position:relative;
  
}



.sg-multicolor {
list-style:none;
width:100%;
font-size:0;
padding:0px;
position:absolute;
bottom:0px;
}

.sg-multicolor li {
display:inline-block;
width:33.3%;
height:5px;
  
}

.sg-multicolor li:nth-child(1) {
background:#F05757;
}

.sg-multicolor li:nth-child(2) {
background:#FAD46B;
}

.sg-multicolor li:nth-child(3) {
background:#08B5CC;
}
```

```html
<div class='sg-container'>
<ul class='sg-multicolor'>
<li></li>
<li></li>
<li></li>


</ul>

</div>
```